# segmentation fault using scanf to read doubles

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm writing the input section for an assignment, if a command line input is one it's supposed to take keyboard input - one of these inputs isn't working.

this is the code segment that I'm having issues with. if the line scanf("%lf %lf", &r1, &r2); is left alone it gives a segmentation fault - if it's changed to write to another variable then everything works. I'm struggling to see why it is that variable that's causing problems, it's literally pasted from the line above, I changed four characters from k to r and the two variables are declared in the same line!! please help asap, there's not a lot I can do until I can fix this issue. I've tried changing the variable names to l1 and l2, but I couldn't think of anything else to do when the dysfunctional line is so similar to functional lines

```
    double  time[10000], x1[10000], x2[10000], v1[10000], v2[10000];
double  m1, m2, k1, k2, r1, r2, w1, w2;
int     count, inmethod;

time[0] = 0;
x1[0] = 0;  x2[0] = 10;
v1[0] = 0;  v2[0] = 0;
m1 = 5;     m2 = 5;
k1 = 5;     k2 = 5;
r1 = 5;     r2 = 10;
w1 = 0;     w2 = 0;

sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &inmethod);
//  printf("%d \n", inmethod);


if((argc == 2) && ((inmethod == 1) || (inmethod == 0)))
{
}

else
{
    printf("enter 1 for file input or 0 to enter input via the keyboard. you will be able to save your input for future use.\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(inmethod == 1)
{
    printf("system properties: \n");

    printf("please enter m1 then m2, seperated by a space and followed by enter\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &m1, &m2);

    printf("please enter k1 then k2, seperated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &k1, &k2);

    printf("please enter r1 then r2, seperated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &r1, &r2);

    printf("please enter w1 then w2, seperated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &w1, &w2);

    printf("initial conditions: \n");

    printf("please enter x1[0] then x2[0], seperated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x1[0], &x2[0]);

    printf("please enter v1[0] then v2[0], seperated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &v1[0], &v2[0]);

}
```

Comment: If you want to convert a string you have to a number, like you do with `argv[1]`, then you might want to use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead. You might also want to check `argc` *before* doing it.

Comment: I/O can fail, so you need to check the return value of `scanf()` (and `sscanf()`) before relying on the results.

Comment: @joachimpileborg - the inputs aren't necessarily going to be integer though :/

Comment: @unwind what should I check for? we were shown maybe twenty different input validation methods while being taught other things and came to the mob consensus that they make no sense.

Comment: Works for me. All inputs are doubles, except the first parameter. Are you mixing . and , when typing floating point numbers?

Comment: For those cases then `scanf` is probably the best bet (though there is of course [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)). I meant that `sscanf` when you convert `argv[1]` to an integer might not be the best.

Comment: I'll check the punctuation @nmenzes

Comment: Please provide a decent title for your question. How do you think you will interest people in looking inside?

Comment: @joachimpileborg I'll look into changing that but it works atm :p

Comment: It compiles fine when I copy & paste your code to my machine... just added a main to run. Can you show examples of your input?

Comment: I just typed random numbers. if this section works when you compile it I'll check how the r values are used, though they work with the initial values so I have no idea why changing them could cause an issue.

Comment: @nmezes, you were right - the problem was with input. I forgot to follow the initial conditions validation rules that I was going to code after I got this working so the rest of the simulation took impossible initial values and did strange things. I tried a set of acceptable values and it worked, there was nothing wrong with the code other than the absence of the next thing I was going to add - just me being stupid. thanks for your help

Comment: @nmenezes - if you let me know how to accept your comment as a answer for some rep or however this site rewards the helpful I will, your input was really useful.

Comment: Spelling hint: There's A RAT in SEPARATE. And not checking the return value of scanf is asking for disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code looks ok. It compiles for me and works fine.

Please check your input values. scanf is really weak for input validation, you need to check the function return and get ready for the worse. If you need to accept keyboard input like this, try to use gnu readline or a library with a better input function.